# Move values within php array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to build something on top of a wordpress plugin. 
For this I need to add more content to an existing array.

This would be the current result from the array:

```
$formField = [
    'key' => 'my-key',
    'value' => 'my-value'
];
```

But I would like to get the content nested, so I can add more indexes.

This would be the disired output:

```
$formField = [
    '0' => [
        'key' => 'my-key',
        'value' => 'my-value'
    ]
];
```

I thought of this:

```
if ( array_key_exists('key', $formField)) {
    $formFieldTemp = $formField;
    $formField = [];
    $formField[0] = $formFieldTemp;
}
```

Than I can add more content with:

```
$formField[] = ["key" => "new-key", "value"=>"new-value"];
```

**My question is: Isn't there a better way to nest the existing content in this array?**

Comment: `$newArray[]=$formField;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap `$formField` in an array `[$formField]` and set it again instead of creating `$formFieldTemp`:

```
$formField = [
    'key' => 'my-key',
    'value' => 'my-value'
];

if (array_key_exists('key', $formField)) {
    $formField = [$formField];
}

print_r($formField);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => my-key
            [value] => my-value
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

These three lines should do it for you. If you're sure it'f an array you can remove the first one.

```
is_array($formField) or $formField = [];
array_key_exists('key', $formField) and $formField = [ $formField ];
$formField[] = ["key" => "new-key", "value"=>"new-value"];`
```